# beego binary is installed an absurd path and 'bee new' command doesn't work

Tags: go, ubuntu-18.04, beego, gopath

I installed almost 10 days ago golang in my Ubuntu 18.04.01 Server Edition:

```
go version
go version go1.10.4 linux/amd64
```

The GOPATH set in .bashrc is this:

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=${PATH}:${GOPATH}/bin
```

and I've been using golang since then.
Today I tried to install beego but happens something really strange:

```
go get -u github.com/astaxie/beego
go get -u github.com/beego/bee
```

The binary file is installed in a very long, and actually strange and absurd  path:

```
marco@pc01:~/go/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:
/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin$ ls -lah
total 16M
drwxrwxr-x 2 marco marco 4.0K Jan 30 17:14 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 marco marco 4.0K Jan 30 17:14 ..
-rwxrwxr-x 1 marco marco  16M Jan 30 17:14 bee
```

While the src beego directory seems correctly installed:

```
/home/marco/go/src/github.com/beego/bee
```

What is strange, again, is that if try to execute this simple go code:

```
package main

import (
        "github.com/astaxie/beego"
)

type MainController struct {
        beego.Controller
}

func (this *MainController) Get() {

        this.Ctx.WriteString("hello world")

}

func main() {

        beego.Router("/", &MainController{})
        beego.Run()

}

go run helloBeego.go
2019/01/30 17:37:06.139 [I]  http server Running on http://:8080
```

And in the web browser I actually get:

```
hello world
```

But when I try to create a bee project:

```
/go/src$ bee new my-first-beego-project

Command 'bee' not found, did you mean:

  command 'be' from deb bugs-everywhere
  command 'btee' from deb ruby-bcat
  command 'beef' from deb beef
  command 'bbe' from deb bbe
  command 'ben' from deb ben
  command 'beet' from deb beets
  command 'beep' from deb beep
  command 'see' from deb mime-support
  command 'ree' from deb ree
  command 'pee' from deb moreutils
  command 'beer' from deb gerstensaft
  command 'tee' from deb coreutils
  command 'bel' from deb belier
```

I guess that the absurd path in which bee binary is put  and the fact that creation of bee project with 'bee new' command fails are related problems.
How to solve them?
Looking forward to your kind help.
Marco

Added info, as rightly requested:

```
marco@pc01:~$ go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/home/marco/.cache/go-build"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/marco/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/lib/go-1.10"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/go-1.10/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-
map=/tmp/go-build461259545=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
marco@pc01:~$
```

Version of beego:

```
v1.6.2
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to add the output of `go env`?

Comment: May or may not be related, but don't set `PATH` variables in an rc file. Always use one of the profile files.

Comment: @Adrian I added more info above

Comment: Try again with go 1.12?